# Add an audit rule to an Active Directory Organizational Unit with powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, organizational-unit

In the powershell script below, I am collecting Active Directory audit rules for a specific OU, checking if any audit rules exist for a failure, and adding a failure audit rule if one does not exist.  Everything works until the last step of adding the failure rule.  There is no error message, but the new rule does not appear in active directory.

```
#find the needed OU
Import-Module activedirectory
Set-Location ad:
dir

#get an acl object based for the OU
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "DC=something,DC=somethingElse" -Audit
$auditRules = $acl.GetAuditRules(1,1,[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$foundFailRule = $false
foreach ($rule in $auditRules) {
    if ($rule.AuditFlags -ieq "Failure") {
        $foundFailRule = $true
        break
    }
}
if ($foundFailRule -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "Found fail rule.  No action needed."
}
else {
    #find the IdentityReference from the first audit rule entry in the OU
    $identityReference = $auditRules[0].IdentityReference
    $activeDirectoryRights = "GenericAll"
    $auditFlags = "Failure"
    $failAuditRule = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAuditRule $identityReference, $activeDirectoryRights, $auditFlags
    $acl.AddAuditRule($failAuditRule)
}
```

Not sure if this is significant, but I noticed that in the default audit rules for the OU, sometimes the ObjectType and InheritedObjectType is a string of all zeros, and other times it contains some non-zero data.  With the constructor method above, those properties default to all zeros.

Any idea why the AddAuditRule Method is not generating a new rule on the OU?  Since there is no error, maybe it is adding a rule, but it is populating in Active Directory at an unexpected location?